# Tokenize in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tokenize

I am trying to build a function that python that allows me to tokenize a character string. I have performed the following function:

```
def tokenize(string):
words = nltk.word_tokenize(string)
return words
```

This function prints the following:

```
tokenize("Hello. What’s your name?")
```

`['Hello', '.', 'What', '’', 's', 'your', 'name', '?']`

But I need you to print me as follows:

`['Hello', '.', 'What’s', 'your', 'name', '?']`

How could I implement it?.
Thank you

Comment: Maybe something with a regex? `re.findall(r"[^\W\d_]+(?:['’][^\W\d_]+)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[^\w\s]|_", text)`, see https://ideone.com/f06Xd3

Comment: You could postprocess the output of `word_tokenize` to concatenate the three strings you want to be one into one and replace them in the list with that one string.  That may not be what you want to do in general, though.  The general specification is not clear.

Comment: Maybe it is a bit simple, but I try not to separate `"what" and "´" and "s"` in the word what's, but when I tokenize it returns only a `"what's"`